# Passing Node FileStream Image to HTML5 FileReader API

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, filereader

How can I use Node FileSystem to open a file but have it sent to and read by the **[FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)**?

```
const myFile = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Image.png";

fs.readFile(myFile, (error, data) => {
    const blob = new Blob(data);

    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);

    fileReader.addEventListener("load", () => {
        const image = new Image();
        image.src = fileReader.result;

        document.body.appendChild(image);
    });
});
```

This code doesn't throw an errors, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Node doesn’t have `FileReader`, nor `Blob`, `Image`, `document`. Where are you getting them from?

Comment: I'm building an Electron application which uses Node.js and standard Web APIs.

Comment: The `Blob` constructor requires an array. Does `new Blob([data])` work? Also, why not just `image.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)` instead of using `FileReader`? Also also, note that you need to escape backslashes in your string, as in `"C:\\Users\\Me\\Image.png"`. Should probably check the value of the `error` parameter, too.

Comment: My file path is a bad example, in my application I retrieve the file path through a dialog.  I'm using FileReader to facilitate other drag-and-drop code, which I want to reuse for selecting an image with a dialog window.  Unfortunately, binary encoding doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Check the error parameter, It may contains some errors.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong, @Ryan solution does work.  I was just trying to read the image before it was loaded.  Of interest, "binary" encoding isn't necessary as it seems to work without, unless that's the default when unspecified.

Comment: TheDarkIn1978 + @Kaiido: You don’t want an encoding. A `Buffer` is also a `Uint8Array`, which `Blob` accepts. Do not use strings to represent binary data (which is what `'binary'` does). Anyway, you should still be able to use `URL.createObjectURL`, and maybe even an `<input type="file">` – read its `files` property on the `change` event and there’ll be no need to muck with `fs` (but I don’t know if that works in Electron).

Comment: @Ryan, you're right, but it wasn't obvious that electron's implementation of Blob would accept node's object at all.

Comment: It is now possible to use `<input type="file">` in Electron, but Electron's Dialog is much more customizable, relies on Node's FS.  However, the main reason i'm using it is because it's not possible to activate `<input type="file">` from Electron's Menu.  Calling `click()` on the element will call its event handler but the file dialog will not open.  It only works if the element is actually clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the participants in the discussion above, the following code is a working solution.  I've purposefully left out error handling for brevity.

```
const nodeFileSystem = require("fs");

const filePath = "C:\\path\\to\\image\\file.png";

nodeFileSystem.readFile(filePath, (error, data) => {

    const blob = new Blob([data]);

    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    fileReader.addEventListener("load", fileReaderLoadHandler);
});

function fileReaderLoadHandler(event) {

    const fileReader = event.target;
    fileReader.removeEventListener("load", fileReaderLoadHandler);
    
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = fileReader.result;
    image.addEventListener("load", imageLoadHandler);
}

function imageLoadHandler(event) {

    const image = event.target;
    image.removeEventListener("load", imageLoadHandler);

    document.body.appendChild(image);
}
```